# Cannot find module '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect' from 'jest.setup.js'

Tags: reactjs, ts-jest

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';


expect(screen.getByText('User does not exist.')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

I'm writing the unit test for my web app, I use toBeInTheDocument() in my code, but after i run npm test in terminal, it shows that 'Cannot find module '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect' from 'jest.setup.js''.

I have a jest.setup.js file which includes the code:require('@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect');

and also a jest.config.js file which includes the code:
setupFilesAfterEnv:["./jest.setup.js"],

and I also import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'; in my test.tsx file, also check the node_modules there is @testing-library/jest-dom under it.
what should I do now?`

Answer (score 42):

This was [a breaking change in version 6.0](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/releases/tag/v6.0.0) that removed the extend-expect entry point in favor of a default entry point and some platform specific ones. For my use case, the default entry point worked:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```

Answer (score 14):

Remove extend-expect from your import:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```

Answer (score 4):

I also encountered the same problem, and the issue was with the **@testing-library/jest-dom version 6.1.4**, which I changed to **version 5.16.5**

Comment: shouldn't have downgraded, there are security vulnerabilities in 5.16.5 - the answer is pretty clear above in saying you need to update your import to only be `import '@testing-library/jest-dom'`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `setupFilesAfterEnv: ["@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"]` to `setupFilesAfterEnv: ["@testing-library/jest-dom"]` in jest.config.js file worked fine.